# How to add text annotation by using css+js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The picture is the effect I want, but the method to achieve this effect is not particularly ideal.

[image]

I use position and inline-height to add notes to the text, but in actual application the program is dynamic, so it is very difficult to calculate the position.

Do you have other ways to achieve the effect of adding comments under the text?

```css
.container {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: normal;
}

.text-red {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.text-red-tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 25px;
  color: red;
}

.text-green {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.text-green-tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span>green and</span>
<span class="container">
  <span class="text-red">
    blue, green and blue Pink，purple,orange,
    <span class="text-green">black and white,
      <span class="text-green-tag">Green tag</span> 
    </span>
    Pink，purple, orange, black and white, stand up, sit down, turn around. Pink，purple, orange, black and white.3. BingoThere was a farmer had a dog, and bingo was h ay friday Saturdaysunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday Saturday6.
  </span>
  <span class="text-red-tag">Red tag</span>
</span>
<span> 
  Little pigOink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig Oink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig7. I ‘m hungryI'm a little hungry,I'm hungry.Have som  e pigOink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig Oink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig7. I ‘m hungryI'm a little hungry,I'm hungry.Have so
</span>
```

Comment: How do you determine if you need a red or green tag? Can you select text or is it for specific words?

Comment: Only way I can see the vertical positioning working without any extra calculation logic, would be if you can make it dependent on the nesting level. But that would probably only be an option, if that is somewhat limited.

Comment: @CBroe I have also used the nesting level, and the nesting is almost ready to show the red and green lines. But the distance between the red line and the green line, as well as the distance of the tag text they contain, it is difficult to control.

Comment: @Reyno The method of selecting text has been implemented through Window.getSelection. I will get an array that contains the start index and the end index, color. but I cannot display it dynamically through position, inline-height.

Comment: I am searching for a long time. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.